# How to find an azure vm cpu utilization statistics, using python azurerm sdk

Tags: python, azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-sdk-python

I am not able to find the cpu utilization of an azurerm using azurerm python sdk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Ramani, I don't know there are any APIs of Azure SDK for Python which can directly get the Azure VM CPU utilization data, even Azure REST APIs.

However, there is a way to help you getting the VM diagnostic data which includes CPU utilization, please see below.

1. You need to refer to the article [Microsoft Azure Virtual Machine Monitoring with Azure Diagnostics Extension](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/windows-azure-virtual-machine-monitoring-with-wad-extension/) to save the diagnostic data into Azure Table Storage if you are using Windows VM. For Linux VM, please see the article [Use the Linux Diagnostic Extension to monitor the performance and diagnostic data of a Linux VM](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-linux-classic-diagnostic-extension/).
2. Then, you can view the diagnostic data via the tool [`AzureStorageExplorer`](http://storageexplorer.com/), and get these data [using Python SDK for Azure Table Storage](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-python-how-to-use-table-storage/) and filter the data you need.

Comment: Thank you so much Peter Pan for the information. I will try the scenarios by following the above mentioned steps.